# IE8, Google Maps v3, "Stack overflow at line: 24" main.js

Tags: google-maps

On a map with just three pins, I'm getting "Stack overflow at line: 24" in main.js of Google Maps v3, on IE8 only. All the other major browsers are good.

Pressing F12 to get into the IE8 debugger lets me single step through the code, but ends up in a minified jumble with a long stack trace of anonymous functions.  The stack overflow happens after the map is fully initialized.

Any clues?

Comment: You answered your own question at the same time as asking it? What's going on?

Comment: Yeah, what @Floris said... show us your code and it might help us to debug it for you

Answer (score 0):

IE8 gets unhappy if nulls are passed into the LatLng constructor:

```
pos = '';
pos = pos.split(",");
latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos[0],pos[1]);
```

Comment: Yep, that's what was happening.